# How to prevent to create duplicate node on clicking submit button multiple time

Tags: forms

I am using unique_field module.
If a node already created and i want to create node with duplicate title(title is selected as unique field), it work fine. But if i click on submit button multiple time(suppose 4 times) with node data, then 4 node created with same data.

I have already tried with hook_node_validate but it does not work.

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit maybe?

Comment: I have checked this module but it is JavaScript/Jquery based module. But i don't want to use any JavaScript/Jquery for this. If any other options are there please share..but no Jquery.

Comment: I don't know that there's a non-javascript solution to this, except for not hitting the button multiple times when submitting. You have to use the tools that are available for certain jobs, and javascript is the tool for this particular job

Comment: @clive s solution is whats worked for me in something similar.  However I also looked at https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field .  how about that ?

Comment: I am using that module but it does not work is this case. Actually it was working perfect one or two month ago and after that we have made many changes and this issue is appearing.